# Get Selected Item from List

Tags: java, libgdx, game-development

I'm currently creating an inventory system, in which the user will select an item from a list and the icon on the right will update based on the item that the user has picked.

I need a way to get the list item that  the user has currently selected. I then need to use that list item to display an icon which the user will see.

Currently I have tried using the getSelected() method on the inventory list, which seems to be only returning the first item in the list. I need a way to get the item that the user has currently selected.

I need to get the current item selected on the list called 'inventory'.

```
package com.sps.game.inventory;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input;
import com.badlogic.gdx.InputProcessor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.*;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.*;

import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.FitViewport;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.Viewport;
import com.sps.game.controller.InventoryController;
import com.sps.game.controller.PlayerController;

public class PlayerInventory {
    public Stage stage;
    public SpriteBatch sb;
    private Viewport viewport;

    private Skin skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("core/assets/pixthulhuui/pixthulhu-ui.json"));

    private List<Item> inventory;
    private List<Image> itemImages;

    private InventoryController inventoryController;
    private InputProcessor oldInput;


    public PlayerInventory(SpriteBatch sb, PlayerController playerController) {
        this.sb = sb;
        viewport = new FitViewport(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), new OrthographicCamera());
        stage = new Stage(viewport, sb);

        inventoryController = new InventoryController();
        inventory = inventoryController.getInventoryList();
        itemImages = inventoryController.getImageList();
    }

    private void formatting() {
        stage = new Stage();
        Label inventoryLabel = new Label("Inventory", skin);
        Label imageLabel = new Label("Item", skin);

        Table table = new Table(skin);
        table.setDebug(true);
        table.defaults();
        table.center();
        table.setFillParent(true);
        table.add(inventoryLabel);
        table.add(imageLabel);
        table.row();


        table.add(inventory); //need a way to get the current item selected 
        table.add(itemImages.getSelected()); 

        stage.addActor(itemImages);
        stage.addActor(table);
    }
    public void setInput() {
        oldInput = Gdx.input.getInputProcessor(); //Get the old input from the user.
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);       //Set the input to now work on the inventory.
    }

    public void update() {
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.I) && oldInput == null) {
            formatting();
            setInput();
        }

        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.O) && oldInput != null) {
            stage.dispose();
            Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(oldInput);
            oldInput = null;
        }
    }

    public void dispose() {
        stage.dispose();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please, add code witch describe `Item` class

Comment: I don't think that is required to solve this issue. The inventory collection is simply a list of Item objects. Each item is responsible for it's own icon, which can be retrieved by calling the getImage() method.

Comment: How do you know what the player currently has selected?

Comment: Please consider editing this question instead of posting another one with the details you provided in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55090321/updating-image-in-table That is the purpose of the Edit function. Delete one of the two questions, here's how: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300117/how-do-i-close-or-delete-a-question-that-i-have-asked

Comment: The two questions are not the same. They both have similar, but distinct code that refers to different issues that I was facing. I will not be deleting the question as both of these questions may help others with the same issue.

Comment: I see you solved the problem of getting a selected item from the list in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55090321/updating-image-in-table/55092871#55092871. Please consider adding a self-answer to this question so more people in the community get benefited. This community even encourages that! :D https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer. As soon as I posted this comment you answered your own question, I feel so dumb haha

Comment: Already done that. Thanks for taking the time to look through my code and help me out. I've spent almost all of today trying to figure this out. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution, through using a Clicklistener.

```
    inventory.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
            String clickedItem = inventory.getSelected();
            table.add(clickedItem);
            System.out.println(item.getName());
            }
        });
```